# How do I fix black screen issue on my laptop?

Tags: 14.04, lts, youtube

I recently updated my computer to 14.04 LTS and since I did so, every time I play youtube videos, the screen on my laptop goes black. I can still hear sound, but I get no image at all. I know clean installing would probably fix it, but is there a simpler way to fix this? Thank you

Comment: There are so many possible answers to your problem, as many as there are possible causes.  Please clarify your question by listing which browsers you have tried viewing it with so far, and possibly even link one of the videos in case there's something peculiar about the videos you are attempting to view.

Comment: It MIGHT also be helpful if you listed the brand and model of your computer, specific cpu variety if known, especially if it is a laptop.  I'm asking because I encountered a similar malfunction of a friend's rather old AMD laptop.  It's cpu had a characteristic which flash no longer supports, and as a result youtube videos could only be viewed with the assistance of a particular firefox web browser plugin.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry about that. I'm still pretty new to ubuntu. I primarily used Chrome, but I switched to chromium yesterday. The issue went away for what was left of last night, and then it persisted today. I have an older Toshiba Satellite A305 Series. From what I've been searching online it says it has to do with the version of flash, and I've tried updating and reinstalling chrome, but no dice.

Comment: @gyropyge my cpu is from the Intel Centrino series

Comment: It looks like I may have guessed your problems correctly then.  I will attempt to see if I can find the explanation online and remember what the plugin was that fixed my friend's laptop.  It was the sort of solution I ought to have realized I'd need again as old laptops aren't getting any younger.

Comment: @gyropyge I appreciate it, thank you so much. I'm in my finals week, and it'd be helpful so I could watch math videos. Thank you

Comment: looks like we were both typing concurrently.  I discovered I was thinking of the AMD model XP series CPU.  If you have intel it won't be for the same reason but theoretically the architecture could have the same flaw, but that seems unlikely.

What worked to fix my friend's laptop was a plugin which I see chromium appears to offer.  Please go into your chromium menus and look up a plugin called "video converter" and install it.  If you discover you can convert and view videos under an alternate format then something, cpu or display chipsets, are incompatible with your current flash driver.

Comment: I might have to give that a try some other time if any other solution does not appear, but I do appreciate you taking the time to answer my question. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This answer doesn't so much promise to solve the problem as much as to at least permit you to watch videos in the meantime while you are figuring it out.  You may even need to watch a video in order to solve your problem, so, anything that works, right?

If your computer has a working cd/dvd drive, please boot your computer to an ubuntu LIVE CD, such as 12 or 13, connect to the internet with it, and attempt to see if it will display videos.

I am betting it will, and I think you will agree that would be convenient.

Comment: I don't have anything to boot off of at the moment, but I promise I'll give it a shot when I get a chance after my first couple finals this week. Thank you so much for taking the time and helping me with an answer. I really appreciate it